# Can the function $f(x)=x^2$ have an inverse over the set of negative real numbers?

Tags: functions

I'm reading a book about algebraic topology,“A First Course in Topology: An Introduction to Mathematical Thinking”, and there it says:
[image]

Here it is said that the inverse of f is defined for all B in Y. Now, let X and Y be the set of all real numbers and f be the square function. The set of negative real numbers is a subset of Y, and, therefore, is in P(Y), the power set of Y, yet, to what element in P(X) does it relate? The empty set?
Well, if such a function is well defined, then its domain can be extended also to the complex numbers, to the letters of the alphabet and to whatever element one wishes, so if one plugs an orange or a person in this function, it will return the empty set, by the reasoning that whatever element that is not a square of a real number has the empty set as its output in such a function.
So, can a function whose domain is literally everything be said to be well defined?

Comment: You have to note that $f^{-1}(B)$ is a set. For $B = \{ 4 \}$ we have $f^{-1}(B)= \{ -2,2 \}$

Comment: Maybe you have to read all paragraph... What is $Y$? the [Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)) of $f$?

Comment: If so, in your example with $^2 : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ we have that $Y \subseteq \mathbb R$ is the set of non-negative numbers. Thus, the above definition applies to every $B \subseteq \mathbb R^{\ge 0}$.

Comment: It's fine to define a slightly different $f:\mathbb R\to \left(\mathbb R \cup \left\{, \right\}\right)$, $f(x) = x^2$. Then it's true that $f^{-1}\left(\left\{\right\}\right) = \emptyset$.

Comment: This function $f^{-1}$, even though it shares the same name, is not the inverse of $f$. The inverse of $f:X\to Y$ would be a function from $f^{-1}:Y\to X$. The $f^{-1}$ in your definition is a function $f^{-1}:P(Y)\to P(X)$, where $P(X),P(Y)$ are the sets of subsets of $X$ and $Y$,respectively. In the case of $f(x)=x^2, X=\mathbb{R}, Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $B=(-\infty,0))$, then $f^{-1}(B)=\emptyset$.

Comment: Ok, let F be the inverse function of f, f being the square function. If F(B) is a set and if F is defined for all B in R, the set of real numbers, what is the set represented be F(B) if B is the set of negative real numbers?

Comment: What is the domain of your new $f$, the square function? $f^{-1}(B)$ is different depending on whether the domain of $f$ is just (some) real numbers or complex numbers.

Comment: "4.1. Definition. Let X and Y be sets. A function f from X to Y is a subset of X × Y such that whenever (x, y1) and (x, y2) both belong to the subset f, then y1 = y2."

Comment: If $f$ is the square function, there is no $B$ in the set of negatives, because no square can be negative. Please, consider again the formula above for the case with the square function: $... x^2 \in B$. This implies that there are no negative numbers in $B$.

Comment: By definition 4.1, can't I state X=Y=R for a square function?

Comment: Indeed there are no negative numbers in B, if B is to be taken from Y and if B is to be a set of numbers that are the square of a real number, but it is said F, inverse of f, is defined for all B in Y.

Comment: You can, $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, then $f^{-1}\left(\mathbb R_{<0}\right) = \left\{x\in\mathbb R:x^2\in\mathbb R_{<0}\right\} = \emptyset$, because no real number $x$ would give negative $f(x)$.

Comment: But it is quite vain to define the domain for any inverse function then, is it not? Why don't we just say that the domain of the inverse of a function is anything, since any value can be plugged into it and return the empty set as its output?

Answer (score 1):

First, you said "the inverse of f is defined for all B in Y", and that's not true. Because the language used by mathematicians here is incredibly confusing, let me call out three concepts so we're all starting with the same understanding. When you have a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$:

- For any $A \subset X$ you have the **image** of $A$, written $f(A)$.
- There may or may not be an **inverse function** to $f$, which is written $f^{-1}$.
- For any $B \subset Y$ you always have an **inverse image** of $B$, written $f^{-1}(B)$.

Notice that we always have "inverse images", even when an inverse doesn't exist. If there is an inverse, then the inverse image is the image under the inverse, but there isn't always an inverse.

Also, your text wants to use $f^{-1}$ for the function that $f$ induces from $P(Y)$ to $P(X)$ by taking the inverse image. I guess that's okay, although lots of texts don't bother with this, and and it creates yet another thing that the symbols "$f^{-1}$" might be referring to when you see it. Personally, I think they're just creating more chances for confusion, but I've never written a topology text.

Okay, now to what I think is your key question, the issue of extending functions. Yes, if $f$ is squaring, then $f^{-1}(\mathbb R ^-) = \emptyset$. And yes, like you said, we could start extending the things for which $f^{-1}(B)$ is defined. But so what? Suppose we have $g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R, g(x) = x^3$. Well, $g$ maps $0$ to $0$. And we could start enlarging the domain of $g$, and map all sorts of odd things to $0$ too. But why? I wonder if the empty set seems like something special to you, like a NULL, or an error condition, in programming. But in math it's just another element of $P(X)$.

Plus, one key reason why it doesn't really make sense to do this in topology, is that in topology what we really want to know about is sets (and their shapes). We're just using functions between them to explore their shapes - changing the domain of your functions means you're no longer looking at the same topological space.

It would be kind of like shopping for a new car, and the salesperson keeps talking about some feature that a different model, with a different price tag, has. I want to know all about the model I'm considering buying - stop changing the subject!

[Oh, also, in math there is no "everything", no set that contains every element. So there's no function whose domain is everything. You can always add a new element to a function's domain, but that produces a new function, an "extension" of the first function.]

Comment: Thanks for the reasoning! Now I understood it.

Comment: @IgorPaulino - Glad it helped. And there are now two things you can possibly do: If you think this is a useful answer, click the up-arrow button on the left hand side. And, as the one who asked the question, if you think this is the best answer, and fully answers your question, you can click the check-mark, and set this as the "accepted answer". (Plus, I get some points if/when you do either of them. :-) )

Comment: "Notice that we always have "inverse images", even when an inverse doesn't exist." In order to avoid possible misunderstandings, for the format I'd rather use $f^{\leftarrow}(B)$ and name it "preimage".

Comment: Well, the text uses both terms, and any student will have to be prepared to see the more confusing version used in some place. And if you use that "raised arrow" version, well, yes, no-one will confuse it with the other symbol, but I'm also afraid no-one around you will understand your potato.